# Is this the opposite of 'making a virtue out of a necessity'?

Tags: phrases, expressions

We all know what it means to 'make a virtue out of a necessity'. The only bananas on offer at the supermarket are 'fair trade', so we buy them and then pretend to ourselves and others that we have done something virtuous. Or a company is obliged by its employment contracts to pay double the statutory severance terms, but it parades the fact of having done so as generosity on its part.

But I am thinking of a slightly different situation. Let us consider the case of low-energy light bulbs.  It is my contention that they do not give off as much light as the old equivalent high-energy ones. But we are using them as a contribution to saving the planet from global warming. But what I find particularly annoying is people who will insist that the bulbs give the same light value.

One sees this attitude all the time. Because something has virtue, yet incorporates drawbacks, some people will insist that the drawbacks do not exist.

Does this amount to the corollary i.e. does it 'make a necessity out of a virtue'? Or how else do we describe such thinking?

Comment: Blind faith perhaps?

Comment: confirmation bias?

Comment: You do have a strange perspective. Since your example company must have drawn up its employment contracts in the first place, obviously they *are* being "generous" if those contracts stipulate "better than the legal minimum". Equally obviously, companies selling low-energy bulbs as "equivalent to X watts" will tend to make that comparison with *less efficient* incandescent bulbs. If your new 10 watt CFL doesn't give as much light as your old 50 watt bulb, buy a 15 watt CFL - you'll have more light and *still* save money and the environment.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The 'generous' company gave better contracts as part of a collective bargaining agreement. Now they are parading it as a virtue. That was my point. As for bulbs, the fact that they overstate the equivalence is precisely my point. An old-fashioned bulb in our downstairs loo just blew last night. The low-energy one I replaced it with is so dim I can't see to pee.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking companies aren't people, so it's misplaced anthropomorphism to classify them as generous or niggardly. But since they *are* a necessary part of modern civilisation, their primary imperative is to ensure their own survival so they can provide employment, goods, and services to *real* people. A company that *actually* "over-rewards" its own people (at *any* level within the hierarchy) will probably go out of business, benefiting no-one. But a "good" company probably will try to persuade the staff they're relatively "well-treated", even though the concept is vacuous.

Comment: ...as for the light bulbs, I started switching to LEDs (2-3 times more efficient than even CFLs) over a decade ago, so I'm well aware wattage equivalents are invariably overstated. But I now have an awful lot of cheap light, and I very rarely have to replace a bulb.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: me, too!  My wife hates fluorescents, so I replaced the kitchen 4' fluorescent fixture with a pair of simple hanging fixtures from Ikea, and put equiv. 100 watt LEDs in them.  Very efficient, very bright, we're saving electricity, and the bulbs are rated to last 20 years. Lovely!

Comment: @FumbleFingers As regards companies, I merely used them in an example to illustrate the linguistic figure of 'making a virtue out of a necessity'. I might equally have used civil servants, or clowns in circuses. My point says nothing about whether a 'company' is technically  capable of virtue or sin.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist: When I moved into my house 14 years ago, I put 50-watt halogen bulbs in every socket in my living room simply because I liked the quality of the light. But I've got 4 wall-lights and 4 ceiling units, each with 3 sockets, so that's 24 x 50 = 1200 watts. But I could afford it, and for the first couple of years I didn't give it much thought. Then my social conscience (and my kids! :) finally kicked in. Maybe my 24 x 1-watt LEDs don't give *quite* so much light, but they do make me feel better!

Comment: ...btw - I recently fitted a wall-light cluster with three of the more modern 3-watt LEDs in my father's house, where he wanted a "reading light". Okay - it's 9 watts total, but it's *much* brighter than the single 60-watt incandescent bulb he had before. Which he really appreciates, since he's getting on a bit so he needs more light to see. They're definitely the way to go.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist Perhaps LEDs sense I am a dyspraxic individual, and know they can make a fool of me. Many of the ones I've  installed have not lasted especially long. But buying a bulb used to be like grabbing a box of breakfast cereal. Now, there are mountains of different sizes, shapes, wattages, bayonets or screw, fitting sizes.You need to study half an aisle of bewildering options. I realise a lot of this has nothing to do with LED,  just that there is so much choice available. And I tend to be a person who sees choice as a blight. I mourn the days when a tin of beans was a tin of beans.

Comment: @WS2 You need measure light output with some standard; and [lumens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumen_%28unit%29) are an SI unit.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you are describing is a form of *cognitive dissonance*.

> **Cognitive dissonance**
>
> In psychology, cognitive dissonance is the excessive mental stress and discomfort experienced by an individual who holds two or more contradictory beliefs, ideas, or values at the same time.

When holding contradictory beliefs, such as 'new bulbs are better' and 'bright bulbs are better than dim ones', pointing out the contradiction often leads to an overreaction or denial of the facts on the table.

Comment: +1 for the most apposite answer so far. But is this the corollary to 'making a virtue out of a necessity', or are the two ideas quite unconnected?

Comment: well, 'virtue out of necessity' might be a way of reacting to a C.D. - claiming that X is virtuous to provide a means of resolving the contradiction, I suppose. But there are other ways - like rejecting the fact that the bulbs are dimmer, or saying that you are a nutjob, or dozens of other ways.

Comment: @Oldcat all this is helpful. But I think at this point, until I can think of something better, I'm going to call it 'creating a false paradox out of a virtue'.

Comment: The matter of the dim bulbs came up at Buckingham Palace when the Queen, at a meeting of the Privy Council, was signing her assent to some piece of legislation. Present was Ed Milliband (now leader of the Labour Opposition) then Secretary of State for the Environment, who had been responsible for enforcing the use of low-energy bulbs. Apparently HM, her eyesight failing her,  shot him a look of daggers and muttered something about the bloody lightbulbs. (Well, perhaps not bloody)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if 'making a necessity into a virtue' is the opposite of 'making a virtue out of a necessity', then perhaps.

It think that it might be (vaguely) related to the [Texas Sharpshooter fallacy](http://skepdic.com/texas.html).

With a nod to @ElliottFrisch for leading me to it.

**Edited to Add...**

Consider the example: "The only bananas on offer at the supermarket are 'fair trade', so we buy them and then pretend to ourselves and others that we have done something virtuous."

That is most certainly Texas Sharpshooter Fallacy -- the hit which is circled in this case is the apparently virtuous choice of "fair trade" bananas, when our shot was clearly not voluntary.

As to your refinement of the principle, in which the assertion is made that the drawback does not in fact exist, it seems to me to be a corollary of the TSF.

In my humble opinion, at least.

Comment: Having read the link you gave, I am not clear on how the TSF  relates to the case I have described. Moreover I am puzzled by the assertion: 'Of the thousands of studies of cancer-clusters investigated by scientists in the USA, "not one has convincingly identified an underlying environmental cause" (Gawande)'. For a fact, in Britain they have identified leukaemia clusters close to the AWRE (nuclear war-heads manufacturing) 
facility at Aldermaston, England; and close to the nuclear power station at Windscale, Cumbria. With respect, this sounds like a theory put out by a 'dirty industry'.

Comment: I like the TSF a lot, but I don't see how this relates to that particular fallacy.

Comment: @WS2, where did I assert anything about cancer-clusters?  Color me puzzled.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist It is contained in the link which you quoted, I felt approvingly.

Comment: @WS2 that clears it up.  I didn't read the entire article, just enough to help me connect TSF with your question. I guess I don't feel qualified to judge the case you bring up, but you may have a point.

Answer (score 0):

Why isn't it simply **[overselling](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/oversell)**?

> Exaggerate the merits of:
>   *computer-aided software engineering has been oversold*

Comment: It is more specific than overselling. Moreover this habit is not just that of sales people. It is practised by far and wide by people who support good causes. I have no objection to the good causes, but to their blindness as to the downsides. To my mind it is an equivalent crime to making a virtue out of a necessity, but seemingly the other way round.

Comment: @WS2 The term *overselling* is used idiomatically to refer to anyone who exaggerates the qualities of something when seeking to induce others favorable reaction.

Answer (score 0):

I think the term **specious** might work.

> seeming to be true but in fact wrong

But for your specific case I would just call it a **sham**.

> something that people pretend is good, serious, or honest but is
>   really not

Comment: But they are doing it, in their mind, and perhaps in actuality, for a rightful purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the merits or demerits of the lightbulb question, it has nothing in common with *making a virtue of necessity* except the very general notion of misrepresentation.

*Making a virtue of necessity* means misrepresenting an act to which one was compelled as impelled by a virtuous motive, and I suggest that only misrepresentations in the same domain, the ethical, can be thought of as “corollary” or antonymic or parallel. For instance:

- *Making a necessity of a misdeed* would mean misrepresenting an ignoble act as compelled: “The Devil made me do it!”, or the legend of Cromwell murmuring “Alas, cruel necessity” over the bier of Charles I.
- *Making a misdeed of a virtue* would mean misrepresenting a noble act as ignobly motivated, like the philanthropist who insists that he only gives millions to charity because it saves him millions more in taxes.
- And *Making a necessity of a virtue* would be misrepresenting a noble act as compelled, like the philanthropist who growls that he only gives thousands to the art museum because his wife makes him do it.

Comment: I'm not sure that final item is the most obvious way of looking at it. To me, *making a necessity of a virtue* implies *forcing people to do those things which are considered "virtuous"*. Effectively, *legislative **moralising***.